# Proof a formula for the number of leaves on a tree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I'm having trouble with a proof. I can't see where to go next. Or if I'm using the wrong variable (maybe I should reason from the point of deg(v<sub>i</sub>) instead of n?).

The question is:

"Let $T$ be a tree of order $n>1$. Show that the number of leaves is

$2+\sum_{deg(v_i)\geqslant3}(deg(v_i)-2)$

where the sum is over all vertices of degree 3 or more."

I've started with proof by induction. With step 1:

Suppose $n=2$, Then, since neither vertex has degree 3 or more, the sum equals 0. So

$2+\sum_{deg(v_i)\geqslant3}(deg(v_i)-2)=2+0=2$ There are indeed 2 leaves in a tree with $n=2$, thus this is true.

Now for step 2. Do I continue with "Suppose $n\geqslant k>2$" ? I don't see where to go next. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: do you know how many edges there are in the graph?

Comment: To my knowledge, there are n-1 edges.(thinking how to proceed with this)

Comment: Count the edges - if there are deg $v_i$ edges incident with vertex $i$ and you add these up you count each edge twice, because each edge is incident with two vertices. Then note that $n =\sum 1$ where the sum is taken over the vertices, simply because there are $n$ vertices.

Comment: You can indeed induct on the order: if it is true for all order $n$ trees, removing a leaf from an order $n+1$ tree reduces it to an order $n$ tree. Show that in all ways that the leaf can be removed, the formula for order $n + 1$ can be derived from the formula for order $n$.